# How to speed up performance on my drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Update #2** And... transition was stuck at .35s. Not sure why my CSS wasn't updating : (

**UPDATE:** Is there a way to use requestAnimationFrame to pull this off?

I have a rotating image reel, and I'd like to be able to swipe left and right and switch to the next or previous image (rotating all the image in the set).

I use the `touchmove` event and css `transform: translate` property to move the image, so the swiping left and right is responsive the users touch.

Namely, between when `touchstart`, and `touchend` fire, the `touchmove` event is used to move the actual image, so the user can see something is happening. But,... it's wicked slow. How do I get it to be much more responsive?

Here's the code:

```js
!(function () {
  "use strict"
  window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

    var modules = document.querySelectorAll('a.module')
    var interval

    // This function rotates the modules every 7500 milliseconds.
    function initiateInterval () {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
        modules.forEach(function (module) {
          rotateToNext(module)
        })
      }, 2500)
    }

    initiateInterval() // Kick things off on page load.

    //Be ready to manually switch things on click.
    modules.forEach(function (module) {
      module.addEventListener('click', (event) => switchToManual(module) )
    })

    // Disable clicking while adjusting manually.
    // Then reinitiate the iterval and enable clicking again.
    function switchToManual (module) {
      disableButtons()
      clearInterval(interval)
      cycleTargetToCenter(module, function () {
        initiateInterval()
        enableButtons()
      })
    }

    // Rotate on swipe left or right.
    modules.forEach(function (module) {
      var startPoint
      var endPoint
      module.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
        disableButtons()
        clearInterval(interval)
        return startPoint = event.changedTouches[0].screenX
      })
      module.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        module.style.transform = `translate(${(event.changedTouches[0].screenX - startPoint)}px ,0px)`
      })
      module.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
        module.style.transform = ''
        endPoint = event.changedTouches[0].screenX
        if (endPoint > startPoint + 70) modules.forEach( (mod) => rotateToNext(mod) )
        if (endPoint < startPoint - 70) modules.forEach( (mod) => rotateToPrevious(mod) )
        initiateInterval()
        enableButtons()
      })

    })

    function disableButtons () {
      modules.forEach(function (module) {
        module.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
      })
    }

    function enableButtons () {
      modules.forEach(function (module) {
        module.removeAttribute('disabled')
      })
    }

    function cycleTargetToCenter (module, func) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      if (currentPosition === 'position3') {
        return func()
      } else {
        var spins = decernNumberOfNeededRotations(module)
        for (let i = 0; i < spins; i += 1) {
          modules.forEach( (mod) => rotateToNext(mod) )
        }
        return func()
      }
    }

    function rotateToNext (module) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      var nextPosition = decernNextPosition(module)
      module.classList.remove(currentPosition)
      module.classList.add(nextPosition)
    }

    function rotateToPrevious (module) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      var previousPosition = decernPreviousPosition(module)
      module.classList.remove(currentPosition)
      module.classList.add(previousPosition)
    }

    function decernCurrentPosition (module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position1'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position4'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position5'
    }

    function decernNextPosition (module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position4'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position5'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position1'
    }

    function decernPreviousPosition (module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position5'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position1'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position4'
    }

    function decernNumberOfNeededRotations (module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 2
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 1
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 4
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 3
    }

  })
}());
```

```css
section.modules {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}
a.module {
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 295px;
  height: 295px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  transition: 1s;
}
a.module div.icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -45px;
  top: -45px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
a.module div.copy {
  padding: 42px 2em 2em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
a.module div.copy h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
a.module div.copy h2 p.subtitle {
  font-size: 0.65em;
}
a.module.position1 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(-270px, -90px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px #bababa);
}
a.module.position2 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(-400px, -10px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 12px #bababa);
}
a.module.position3 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 18px #bababa);
}
a.module.position4 {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(400px, -10px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 12px #bababa);
}
a.module.position5 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(270px, -90px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px #bababa);
}
```

```html
<section class="modules"><a class="module module1 position1">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Bulbs
        <p class="subtitle">How many light bulbs?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div></a><a class="module module2 position2">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2>️</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Words
        <p class="subtitle">How many words?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la</p>
    </div></a><a class="module module3 position3">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Queries
        <p class="subtitle">How many queries?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div></a><a class="module module4 position4">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Tubes
        <p class="subtitle">Quantas Tubes?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div></a><a class="module module5 position5">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Actions
        <p class="subtitle">And this too...?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div></a></section>
```

The touch events are slow, it's touch and slide, and then the object almost trails behind like it's lagging. What gives?

Comment: this may help https://betterprogramming.pub/perfecting-drag-and-drop-in-pure-vanilla-javascript-a761184b797a

Comment: I don't think the user needs to drag the card wherever he likes, it may be a good feature for you but it UXly wrong, he only wants to swipe his finger to rotate the cards

Comment: UXly wrong? I mean, I've made my choices UX wise. No need to debate them here. I appreciate the thought though!

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1**: delete `touchmove` event
**Step 2**: change transition to like `.5s`

```js
!(function() {
  "use strict"
  window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {

    var modules = document.querySelectorAll('a.module')
    var interval

    // This function rotates the modules every 7500 milliseconds.
    function initiateInterval() {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        modules.forEach(function(module) {
          rotateToNext(module)
        })
      }, 2500)
    }

    initiateInterval() // Kick things off on page load.

    //Be ready to manually switch things on click.
    modules.forEach(function(module) {
      module.addEventListener('click', (event) => switchToManual(module))
    })

    // Disable clicking while adjusting manually.
    // Then reinitiate the iterval and enable clicking again.
    function switchToManual(module) {
      disableButtons()
      clearInterval(interval)
      cycleTargetToCenter(module, function() {
        initiateInterval()
        enableButtons()
      })
    }

    // Rotate on swipe left or right.
    modules.forEach(function(module) {
      var startPoint
      var endPoint
      module.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        disableButtons()
        clearInterval(interval)
        return startPoint = event.changedTouches[0].screenX
      })

      module.addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {
        module.style.transform = ''
        endPoint = event.changedTouches[0].screenX
        if (endPoint > startPoint + 70) modules.forEach((mod) => rotateToNext(mod))
        if (endPoint < startPoint - 70) modules.forEach((mod) => rotateToPrevious(mod))
        initiateInterval()
        enableButtons()
      })

    })

    function disableButtons() {
      modules.forEach(function(module) {
        module.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
      })
    }

    function enableButtons() {
      modules.forEach(function(module) {
        module.removeAttribute('disabled')
      })
    }

    function cycleTargetToCenter(module, func) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      if (currentPosition === 'position3') {
        return func()
      } else {
        var spins = decernNumberOfNeededRotations(module)
        for (let i = 0; i < spins; i += 1) {
          modules.forEach((mod) => rotateToNext(mod))
        }
        return func()
      }
    }

    function rotateToNext(module) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      var nextPosition = decernNextPosition(module)
      module.classList.remove(currentPosition)
      module.classList.add(nextPosition)
    }

    function rotateToPrevious(module) {
      var currentPosition = decernCurrentPosition(module)
      var previousPosition = decernPreviousPosition(module)
      module.classList.remove(currentPosition)
      module.classList.add(previousPosition)
    }

    function decernCurrentPosition(module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position1'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position4'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position5'
    }

    function decernNextPosition(module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position4'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position5'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position1'
    }

    function decernPreviousPosition(module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 'position5'
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 'position1'
      if (module.classList.contains('position3')) return 'position2'
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 'position3'
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 'position4'
    }

    function decernNumberOfNeededRotations(module) {
      if (module.classList.contains('position1')) return 2
      if (module.classList.contains('position2')) return 1
      if (module.classList.contains('position4')) return 4
      if (module.classList.contains('position5')) return 3
    }

  })
}());
```

```css
section.modules {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

a.module {
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 295px;
  height: 295px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  transition: .5s; // <-- edit this
}

a.module div.icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -45px;
  top: -45px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a.module div.copy {
  padding: 42px 2em 2em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

a.module div.copy h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

a.module div.copy h2 p.subtitle {
  font-size: 0.65em;
}

a.module.position1 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(-270px, -90px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px #bababa);
}

a.module.position2 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(-400px, -10px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 12px #bababa);
}

a.module.position3 {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 18px #bababa);
}

a.module.position4 {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: scale(0.8) translate(400px, -10px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 12px #bababa);
}

a.module.position5 {
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0.6) translate(270px, -90px);
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 8px #bababa);
}
```

```html
<section class="modules">
  <a class="module module1 position1">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Bulbs
        <p class="subtitle">How many light bulbs?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="module module2 position2">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2>️</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Words
        <p class="subtitle">How many words?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="module module3 position3">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Queries
        <p class="subtitle">How many queries?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="module module4 position4">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Tubes
        <p class="subtitle">Quantas Tubes?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="module module5 position5">
    <div class="icon">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h2>Actions
        <p class="subtitle">And this too...?</p>
      </h2>
      <p>La la la...</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Mmm.... I want the module to move along as someone is swiping. That makes it look more real (like you're actually sliding the object over).